# java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.ofbiz.base.util.MessageString

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

i'm using System.Net.Http.HttpClient to POST some values.

in the response string i'm get this error :

\"_ERROR_MESSAGE_\":\"Error calling event: org.ofbiz.webapp.event.EventHandlerException: Problems processing event: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.ofbiz.base.util.MessageString (java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.ofbiz.base.util.MessageString)\"

Please help..

Here's the code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> 
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("USER_FIRST_NAME",userContext.getFirstname()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("CUSTOMER_EMAIL",userContext.getEmail()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("CUSTOMER_COUNTRY",userContext.getCountry()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("CUSTOMER_STATE1",userContext.getState()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("CUSTOMER_CITY",userContext.getCity()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("CUSTOMER_ADDRESS1",userContext.getStreet()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("CUSTOMER_ADDRESS2",userContext.getArea()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("CUSTOMER_MOBILE_CONTACT",userContext.getPhonenumber()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("CUSTOMER_POSTAL_CODE",userContext.getZipcode()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("PASSWORD",userContext.getPassword()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("CONFIRM_PASSWORD",userContext.getCpassword()),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("emailProductStoreId","10112")
            };

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://******/*********/************/", new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData));
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            String responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in the server you are contacting. Nothing we can do anything about or help you with. Contact the company that provides the web service.

Comment: can u plz tell me what is generating the ClassCastException.. I mean what conversion..

Comment: No I can't tell you. As I have said, this is a problem inside the server you are contacting!

Comment: Thanks a lot.. will contact them..